# Передача файла пользователю ASP NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Мне нужно отправить файл пользователю (который будет создан сервером) в раздел загрузок к нему на диск. А также нужно записать этот файл. Хотел бы узнать как вообще это реализуется, желательно с примером.

Comment: Опишите подробней. какого типа файл? как создаётся содержимое? в каком порядке вообще должен работать ваш сценарий?

Comment: Файл .scr это скрипт для автокада. Фунция возвращает строку, которую нужно записать в файл (его нужно создать) и файл отдать пользователю

Comment: Подумайте о: 1) это две разные подзадачи записать в файл и отдать пользователю 2) зачем нужно записать в файл 3) должен ли пользователь ждать когда файл запишется.

Comment: Пользователь вводит параметры по которым рассчитываются координаты, затем  нужно создать файл с этими координатами и пользователь должен скачать файл и уже сам его запустить в автокаде

Comment: пользователь может скачать файл, и при этом его можно не создавать(ну т.е. не сохранять в файловую систему бэкэнда). Если этот файл вам далее на бэкэнде не нужен, его даже не нужно создавать.

Comment: Да, на бэке он не нужен. Можно пожалуйста пример как это реализовать. Ваш ответ подойдёт?

Comment: если бы, я не считал, что он может подойти, я бы не давал его..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у вас уже есть строка в памяти, которую нужно отправить по http как файл, то

```
return File(System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(yourstring), 
            "mime тип вашего файла", 
            "имя_вашего_файла")
```

Ну или не UTF8, а что вам там нужно.

Answer (score 3):

Пример того как это могло бы быть реализовано в методе контроллера:

```cs
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetSomeFile() {
     /// Создаете объект Stream для передачи
     var stream = /* ваш код создания объекта Stream */
     /// Вызов метода из базового класса ControllerBase
     return File(stream, "mime тип вашего файла", "имя_вашего_файла");

}
```

Comment: Если я вместо stream вставлю строку оно будет работать?

Comment: какую строку???

Comment: string с содержимым файла

Comment: Что должен содержать объект stream? Можно пожалуйста пример

Comment: @RedBro stream представляет собой стандартную .Net абстракцию некоего потока данных, как правило это байтовый массив, не обязательно использовать именно stream, вы можете и напрямую передавать байтовый массив клиенту, но что бы он был воспринят как файл вам надо свою строку(раз у вас строка) преборазовать к байтовому массиву, смотрите ответ 4per он вам написал как можно это сделать.